# Split string into two parts only

Tags: python, split

I have a string

```
s = 'abcd qwrre qwedsasd zxcwsacds'
```

I want to split any string in only two parts at the first occurrence of a whitespace. *i.e*. `a='abcd'` and `b='qwrre qwedsasd zxcwsacds'`

If I use `a, b=split(' ')` it gives me an error because there are too many values to unpack.

Comment: Use the `maxsplit` parameter: `a, b = s.split(maxsplit=1)`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could use `a,b = split(' ', 1)`.

The second argument `1` is the maximum number of splits that would be done.

```
s = 'abcd efgh hijk'
a,b = s.split(' ', 1)
print(a) #abcd
print(b) #efgh hijk
```

For more information on the string split function, see [`str.split` in the manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 15):

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

> **str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)**
>
> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter
> string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus,
> the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is not
> specified or -1, then there is no limit on the number of splits (all
> possible splits are made).

```
'1 2 3'.split(maxsplit=1)
# ['1', '2 3']
```

Comment: nice one - is there also a minsplit or something to make this work from reverse?

Comment: I tried testing negative values but that didn't yield that kind of result... I guess it would be running the risk of not being able to split a string a minimum of x ways.

Comment: @sudonym I'm not sure what `minsplit` would do. What is the expected result of `"something".split(minsplit=2)`?

Comment: the operation in reverse, i.e. just split after the first/second last occurrence? I will check the docs.

Comment: @sudonym that's `str.rsplit` -- split from the right, not the left.

Answer (score 12):

You can use a standard string method `partition` which searches for a given separator and returns a 3-tuple consisting of string part before it, the separator itself, and the part after it.

```
>>> s = 'abcd qwrre qwedsasd zxcwsacds'
>>> s.partition(' ')
('abcd', ' ', 'qwrre qwedsasd zxcwsacds')
```

Comment: although this works, I'm not sure how it's better than using `maxsplit` in `str.split`

Comment: @AdamSmith if there is no space in `s` this is a bit more convenient because it will still return a `3-tuple`.

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this problem by using python "star expression".

```
s='abcd qwrre qwedsasd zxcwsacds'
a = s.split()
first, *second = a
second = " ".join(second)
```

"first" takes the first element of the list and " *second" takes the remaining elements.

```
>>> first
'abcd'
>>> second
'qwrre', 'qwedsasd', 'zxcwsacds'
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
s = 'abcd qwrre qwedsasd zxcwsacds'
s1 = s.split()[0]
s2 = ' '.join(s.split()[1:])
print(s1)
print(s2)
```

Output:

```
abcd
qwrre qwedsasd zxcwsacds
```

Or:

```
new_s = ''.join([' s ' if i.isspace() else i for i in s])
a,b = new_s.replace(' s','',1).split(' s ')
print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
abcd
qwrre qwedsasd zxcwsacds
```

Or even better split also for tabs and newlines:

```
a,b = s.split(None,1)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
abcd
qwrre qwedsasd zxcwsacds
```

Answer (score 5):

You're missing one more parameter in your split, the number of occurrences, try this;

```
s='abcd qwrre qwedsasd zxcwsacds'
>>> a, b = s.split(' ', 1)
>>> print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 3):

1.You can split the string like this.

```
a = temp.substring(0, s.indexOf(' '));
b = temp.substring(s.indexOf(' ') + 1);
```

2.or you can do:

```
a = s[0: s.find(' ')]
b = s[s.find(' ') + 1: ]
```

3.

```
a,b = s.split(' ', 1)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

So, there's a second parameter you can pass as many have pointed out:

```
>>> a, b = "foo bar".split(' ', 1)
```

but nobody's pointing this out:

```
>>> a, b = "foobar".split(' ', 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

You don't want to be using this because it's unsafe unless you're guaranteed to have a string that has only the one space in it. It's better to split it and then check for how many splits you've got and then unpack them:

```
>>> parts = "foo bar".split(' ', 1)
>>> if len(parts) == 2:
>>>    a, b = parts
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!python2

s='abcd qwrre qwedsasd zxcwsacds'

s1 = s[0: s.find(' ')]
s2 = s[s.find(' ') + 1: ]

print s1
print s2
'''
abcd
qwrre qwedsasd zxcwsacds
'''
```